# Creating a $variable from a specific part of a txt file

Tags: variables, powershell

I'm trying to get PowerShell to use a specific section of a text file as a `$variable` to be used later in the script.

With `Get-Content` and index I can get to the point of having a whole line, but I just want one word to be the variable, not the whole thing.

The alphanumeric code will always be in the same location exactly
line 5 (counting the first one as 0 of course) and the position in would be between the characters 22 to 30 (or the last 8 characters of that line).

I would like that section of the document to be identified as `$txtdoc`, to be used later in:

```
$inputfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('input5')

$inputfield.value = $txtdoc
```

The txt file contains the following

```
From:   *************
Sent:   *************
To: *******************
Subject:    *************

On-Demand Tokencode: 79960739
Expires after use or 60 minutes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this maybe?

```
$variable = ( gc mytext.txt )[5].substring(21,8)
```

Comment: Im getting the following error:

Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"
At line:1 char:76
+ $input = ( gc D:\Users\userid\Desktop\BPC\Input\input.txt )[5].substring <<<< (22,8)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: @Kirneh the error says that the command cannot find the index then I suppose that the value you gave use are wrong, we need to have your txt file to better help you.

Comment: The contents of the TXT file are as follows (I have edited out personal information from the user)

>From: **************
>Sent: ********************
>To: *****************
>Subject: *******************
>
>On-Demand Tokencode: 79960739
>Expires after use or 60 minutes

basically this numeric code would need to be used later on as input.

Comment: @Kirneh this is a single line , it's impossible find line 5... Open the file in notepad copy and past editing your question ... comments not retains the formatting.. but try `$variable = ( gc mytext.txt )[5].substring(21,8)` maybe is just this

Comment: I have modified my original question to contain the txt

Comment: @Kirneh try now with 21

Comment: it works like a charm, I was on the right track then but just didnt know how to format it. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: @Kirneh glad to help!